# TextBox and Button are not aligning in one line with equal space

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to align a label, textbox and button on a single row with equal spacing between them.

I already aligned elements of protocol_div(label,textbox and button) but for some reason, elements of url_div which have css similar to that of protocol_div, are not being aligned in the same way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXbNW.png)

```css
#protocol_div {
  float: left;
}

#protocol_label_div {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#protocol_select_div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 70px;
}

#protocols_select {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 90%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#open_btn_div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#open_file_button {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0097A7;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#url_div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#url_label_div {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#url_text_div {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#url_text {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
}

#browse_btn_div {
  float: left;
}

#browse_btn {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0097A7;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="protocol_div">
  <div id="protocol_label_div">Protocol</div>
  <div id="protocol_select_div">
    <select size="1" id="protocols_select">
      <option value="file">file</option>
      <option value="hdfs">hdfs</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="open_btn_div">
    <button type="button" id="open_file_button">Open</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="url_div">
  <div id="url_label_div">URL: </div>
  <div id="url_text_div">
    <input type="text" id="url_text"></input>
  </div>
  <div id="browse_btn_div">
    <ReactFileReader multipleFiles={false} fileTypes={[ ".csv"]} handleFiles={this.handleFiles}>

      <button id="browse_btn">Browse</button>
    </ReactFileReader>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```html
<span id="protocol">
  <span class="label_align">Protocol:</span>
  <select size="1" id="protocols_select">
    <option value="file">file</option>
    <option value="hdfs">hdfs</option>
  </select>
  <button id="open_file_button" class="btn">Open</button>
</span>

<span id="url">
  <span class="label_align">URL: </span>
  <input type="text" id="url_text"></input>
  <ReactFileReader 
    multipleFiles={false}
    fileTypes={[".csv"]} 
    handleFiles={this.handleFiles}
  >
    <button id="browse_btn" class="btn">Browse</button>
  </ReactFileReader>
</span>
```

```css
.label_align{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn{
  background-color: #0097A7;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 18px;
}

#protocols_select{
  width:70px;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#url{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#url_text{
  width: 80px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

See it in action here: https://jsbin.com/wukojuxewe/1/edit?html,css,output

Note that I only tested on Chrome on macOS, so additional tweaks may be needed. Also, if you use inline elements (like `<span>`) instead of block elements (like `<div>`), you don't have to deal with floating everything.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to test across your devices and browsers to finalize the logic. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have a height set on #url_text. If you remove that they are all about the same height.

If you want to dive into Flexbox you can really do some powerful stuff including creating a grid (so you can get rid of all those floats) and then also you can align your contents very easily with the space. It makes vertical alignment a breeze.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/